# why can i not read a string* object

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I know this question's is a bit weird but I'm super new to c++ so i have no idea what should I even ask for but,
I am trying to implement a binary tree and i have this function:

```
std::string* Tree::getChildren(int node) {
    std::string children[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        children[i] = tree[2 * node + i];
    }
    return children;
}
```

which I am trying to output like this:

```
std::string* k = t.getChildren(1);
cout << k[0]<<","<<k[1] << endl;
```

but this trows the error:

> Exception thrown at 0x6A46F3BE (ucrtbased.dll) in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC. occurred

What does this mean and what should I do to not have it?

Comment: If you compile with `/W4`, the compiler can [warn about this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/iirmkA).

Comment: If I remember correctly, if the bound is known at compile time, even `std::array<std::string, 2> children;` should work correctly, as well (in addition to `std::vector`).

Comment: When you see highly regular or recognizable patterns like  0xCCCCCCCC, it's often the program trying to tell you something. [Look up the pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Debug_values) to see if there are any hints to be had. Remember that very often the easily recognizable number will be offset somewhat, so if you see 0xCCCCCCFC, it's probably 0xCCCCCCCC + 48.

Answer (score 0):

This creates a local array of `std::string`:

```
std::string children[2];
```

When the function returns, that array is destroyed so the pointer you return immediately becomes invalid.

A better version would be to use the wrapper class for plain arrays, `std::array`:

```
#include <array>

std::array<std::string,2> Tree::getChildren(int node) {
    std::array<std::string,2> children;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        children[i] = tree[2 * node + i];
    }
    return children;
}
```

And use it:

```
auto k = t.getChildren(1);
cout << k[0]<<","<<k[1] << endl;
```